# I cannot install the copy code plugin for docsify

Tags: docsify

I am trying to install the docsify copy code plugin. However it doesn't work nothing change in my HTML yet I did all the required steps to make this works.

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify-copy-code"></script>
<script>
window.$docsify = {

      copyCode: {
        buttonText : 'Copy to clipboard',
        errorText  : 'Error',
        successText: 'Copied'
      },
      plugins: [
        window.DocsifyCopyCodePlugin.init()
      ]
    }
<srcipt>
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order you load scripts is important in docsify.
You start by defining your configuration (`window.$docsify`), then loading the main script and finally adding any plugins.

Here are your tags in the right order so they should work together :

```html
<!-- Configuration -->
<script>
window.$docsify = {
      copyCode: {
        buttonText : 'Copy to clipboard',
        errorText  : 'Error',
        successText: 'Copied'
      }
    }
</script>
<!-- Main Script -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify/lib/docsify.min.js"></script>
<!-- Docsify plugins -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsify-copy-code"></script>
```

Also usage of the init function of plugins is usually not required as they'll init as soon as they load.